# Is there any advantage to bundle all runtime into a standalone file from node_modules/ folder?

Tags: webpack, bundle

### Background

It's all about bundling. Recently, I learned how to use webpack to extract basically every specific module into a standalone file in the output `dist/` folder. At first, I did it only for `@babel/runtime` to check that it is properly polyfilled for things like `Promise`. This cool feature of webpack sparks a question in my mind.

### Question

Now here is my question: What if I extract more than just babel runtime? Does it have any positive effect on the output bundle if I extract more runtime modules from packages into standalone files?